# How to dynamically create component on the fly in Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer

How can I create ad hoc component in Polymer 2 in runtime?

For example i have the following template
`<div>Hello ${name}!</div>`

I receive this template as part of network response.

How can I, based on this template, create new Polymer component 'my-name'?

The bindings needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom element in a file `my-name.html`? If not, you need to create it.

Have you played with the examples at [Try Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour)? When you understand those, look at the `MyElement` examples at [Define an element](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements).

Comment: i’m not able to create file in browser runtime, seems it’s not possible.  But what I think, I can prepare this file at backend and asynchronously import it when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You must have a defined custom element visible to the host page (just like the page's CSS and imports must be visible to it). If you have that, you can create your in JavaScript with `let foo = new MyElement()` and `parentElement.appendChild(foo)`.